# Problem in pausing/resuming Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a maze game. After you press Enter, you can enter a cheat code, also, the timer will pause. But after entering the code, my timer resumes but it decrements 3x each second. Here's the condition for pressing Enter:

```
// gt.setTimer() is called at the moment the maze started
// I'm using getch to trap inputs

else if (move == 13) //Reads if Enter is pressed
            {
                pause = 1; //A Flag saying that the timer must be paused
                gt.setTimer(pause); //Calls my setTimer() method
                Console.Write("Enter Cheat: "); 
                cheat = Console.ReadLine();
                pause = 0; //A Flag saying that the timer should resume
                gt.setTimer(lives, pause); //Calls again the Timer
            }
```

Here's my setTimer() code:

```
static System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
static int gTime = 300;

public void setTimer(int pause)
    {
        t.Interval = 1000; // Writes the time after every 1 sec
        if (pause == 1)
            t.Stop(); // Stop the timer if you press Enter
        else 
            t.Start(); // Starts the timer if not
        t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(showTimer);                       
    }

    public static void showTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Time   " + gTime); //Writes time
        gTime--; //Decrements the time
    }
```

Is there something wrong? Am i missing something?

Comment: why is pause an int, not a bool?

Comment: Where is your synchronization code? You're using multi-threading without synchronization. IMO you shouldn't use multi-threading here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time when you do:
t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(showTimer); 
you add one more event handler to this event

This strind runing only once, in par code where you initialise timer

Comment: hmmm how should i fix this problem? i really need to call the method from time to time.

Comment: try to do t.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(showTimer); before t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(showTimer);

Comment: but better if you initialize event handler somewher in class constructor

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the last line of the `setTimer` method. The timer handler should be registered just once after calling constructor, and not in the `setTimer`. On the elapsed timer event, the handler is called the number of times it has been registered. Thus the more you use operator += more times it being called.

Comment: hmmm how should i fix this problem? i really need to call the method from time to time.

Comment: how would i replace the elapse timer event?

Comment: @Reinan you can unsubscribe from the event at the beginning of the setTimer method using -=, just like you subscribe using +=. Or you can create the timer and subscribe to it from some other part of the code and then start the timer only when you want to begin counting.

Comment: that 'subscribe' thingy is new to me. must give it a try. :>